# android studio - gradle not syncing after installing android studio 3.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've updated my `android studio` to 3.1.3 , after upgrading, my gradle doesn't sync  and it shows me this error :

```
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.0.1/builder-3.0.1.jar'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:198)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.access$300(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$AdaptiveProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.download(ExternalResourceResolver.java:310)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveArtifact(ExternalResourceResolver.java:296)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.0.1/builder-3.0.1.jar'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:81)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.openResource(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.openResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.withContentIfPresent(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:350)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:340)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:117)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.withContentIfPresent(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:196)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:9666 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:388)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:127)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:104)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:95)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    ... 63 more
```

**it doesn't download**

> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.0.1/builder-3.0.1.jar

so it can't sync.

**How can I manually download and add this gradle to my android studio ?**

**Edit**:
this is my **main gradle** file . I tried to use proxy either but it doesn't work

```
    buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Edit:** my up **level gradle** :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.persiandesigners.sima.sima"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
    compile 'me.cheshmak:analytics:2.0.+'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repository.cheshmak.me'
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your gradle file

Comment: have you tried cleaning project? Also, try "invalidate and restart cache" if "clean project" doesn't work.

Comment: @MJM I edit my post and add my gradle file , thanks for reply

Comment: @RachitSeksaria yes it no different

Comment: @johnsmoth add your app level gradle file

Comment: @MJM I add my up level gradle

Comment: "ir.persiandesigners.sima.sima" <= it seems like country where google resides doesn't like country where you reside ... this could be a problem .... go [here](https://www.comparitech.com/privacy-security-tools/blockediniran/) and test https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.0.1/builder-3.0.1.jar

Answer (score 1):

Change to your App level build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }

    }
}
```

And Add this to your Top level build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

}
```

Comment: this will not work out ...because `allprojects` has nothing to do with the `buildscript`. what you are actually doing there, is the define two of the repositories twice, no matter into which `build.gradle` you may add it.

Answer (score 0):

you'd have to update the root-level `build.gradle` to:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }
}
```

also, make sure that gradle isn't in offline mode / or firewalled (in case it still won't download it).

the point is, that the old version `3.0.1` might not be available in the new `google()` repository.

Answer (score 0):

1) Change the **compile** to **implementation**

2)   Update

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()

    }
```

to

```
 repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
 }
```

3) There is one trick use `+` for google and firebase dependencies,once it build successfully use latest version.

```
dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:+'

        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
        implementation 'me.cheshmak:analytics:2.0.+'

        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the android documentation for build dependencies from local environment one can use the configuration as follows:

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Gradle declares dependencies on JAR files inside your project's module_name/libs/ directory (because Gradle reads paths relative to the build.gradle file).

Alternatively, you can specify individual files as follows:

```
    implementation files('libs/foo.jar', 'libs/bar.jar')
```

[Android Build Dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies)

In your case download the necessary jar and put it inside the lib. Surely this is a workaround